# How to change iMessage group chat photo using AppleScript or Javascript?

Tags: applescript, imessage

I couldn't find any help on the internet or the imessage dictionary in the Script Editor. If AppleScript doesn't work, are there any other methods on MacOS? I am hoping to be able to change the profile picture of a group chat to a preconfigured image, just for fun.